Are complexity classes non-monotonic ("dense")?
I am wondering if the following property is true: given any two deterministic time complexity classes $\textsf{DTIME}(f(n))$ and $\textsf{DTIME}(g(n))$, such that $\textsf{DTIME}(f(n)) \subsetneq \textsf{DTIME}(g(n))$, does there exist a class $\textsf{DTIME}(h(n))$ such that
$$
\textsf{DTIME}(f(n)) \subsetneq \textsf{DTIME}(h(n)) \subsetneq \textsf{DTIME}(g(n))?
$$

Isn't $h(n) = \sqrt{f(n)\times g(n)}$ enough?
